# Get substring between two ASCII control characters

Tags: ios, objective-c

Example Response:

```
_STX_<Response>
    <Error>Cancelled</Error>
</Response>
_ETX_<AuditCharacter_not_XML>_EOT_
```

`_VAR_` are actual ASCII Hex codes (reference)

```
_STX_ = 0x02 // start of heading
_ETX_ = 0x03 // end of text
_EOT_ = 0x04 // end of transmission
```

We are doing some integration with some 3rd party devices, one of them we have a socket that reads in a response from the device. We use CocoaAsyncSocket for this. So the data is available to us as NSData or NSString

EG:

```
NSData *strData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [data length])];
NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:strData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

What i am trying to do is get the XML between the ASCII control characters.

One way that works is to do the following (Knowing that NSString is a UTF16)

```
NSRange rSub = NSMakeRange(1, [msg length] - 5);
NSString *sub = [msg substringWithRange:rSub];
```

This correctly returns the XML but this is very limited, what happens when the AuditCharacter is more than 1 byte/char. We should be getting the string between the two control *STX* and *ETX* characters.

We have tried the following

```
unichar STX = 0x02; // \u0002 Start of Text 
unichar ETX = 0x03; // \u0003 End of Text
unichar EOT = 0x04; // \u0004 End of transmission
unichar ACK = 0x06; // \u0006 ACK
unichar NAK = 0x15; // \u0015 NAK

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:msg];
// Tried as NSString
NSCharacterSet *seperator = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"<%c>", ETX]]
// Tried as NSData
NSCharacterSet *seperator = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithBitmapRepresentation:[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:&ETX length:2]]; // tried length as 1 and 2
```

That always seems to just return the whole string.

We then tried using a range

```
NSRange r1 = [msg rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"<%c>", STX]];
NSRange r2 = [msg rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"<%c>", ETX]];
```

But both ranges always return a length of zero.

I know this has to do with the fact that were trying to split/locate the control characters in the string but i am not sure what the correct why to do this would be.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're searching for the string `<_STX_>` with angle brackets, but your actual string doesn't have angle brackets there. Is this a transcription error or there some reason you've added brackets?

Comment: It's also unclear why -5 works in your range, and how that relates to NSString being UTF-16 (it may or may not be UTF-16 internally, and neither `length` nor `substringWithRange:` is based on internal representations anyway).

Comment: To answer both your questions, you are 100% correct i was incorrectly searching for the control character inside <>. I have been staring at this far to long to have even noticed. Reming the <> fixes my issue. 

In regards to the -5 vs -3 i cant tell you, originally i had it as -3 but it would leave to additional chars on the end. I assumed because were converting NSData to NSString it was making the control characters 2 bytes.

Comment: @RobNapier if you make your comment an answer i'll mark it correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're searching for the string `<_STX_>` with angle brackets, but your actual string doesn't have angle brackets there. Just remove the angle brackets.